# Ubuntu 22.04 installed gnome-session-flashback not able to add new menu item

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

Environment:
Windows 10 Home Edition host
VirtualBox running Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

In previous versions of Ubuntu installed gnome-session-flashback and have been able to edit menu **including adding new menu items**

Upon fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04
Items could be removed/moved within a category &etc.
However "New Item" would bring up dialog box but would not process item to add.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community ,  i believe he  is asking of the error thrown when  trying to save the menu item in Alacarte in latest Gnome versions 42 *

Answer (score 1):

Ran menu edit in terminal with privileges:
$sudo alacarte
watching output/stack trace upon submitting 'add item' results:
AttributeError: 'LauncherEditor' object has no attribute 'icon_file'

Checked file/line # in stack trace. (file: usr/share/alacarte/Alacarte/ItemEditor.py) Compared this to working version in Ubuntu 20.04
lines of code: 20.04 --> 269 vs 22.04 --> 293

Backed up 22.04 version of ItemEditor.py
Replaced it with 20.04 version of ItemEditor.py

Menu edits including add item working.

Here is the ItemEditor.py 20.04 version:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#   Alacarte Menu Editor - Simple fd.o Compliant Menu Editor
#   Copyright (C) 2013  Red Hat, Inc.
#
#   This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#   modify it under the terms of the GNU Library General Public
#   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
#   version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#   This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
#   Library General Public License for more details.
#
#   You should have received a copy of the GNU Library General Public
#   License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
#   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA

import gettext
import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, GObject, Gtk
from Alacarte import config, util

_ = gettext.gettext

EXTENSIONS = (".png", ".xpm", ".svg")

def try_icon_name(filename):
    # Detect if the user picked an icon, and make
    # it into an icon name.
    if not filename.endswith(EXTENSIONS):
        return filename

    theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
    resolved_path = None
    for path in theme.get_search_path():
        if filename.startswith(path):
            resolved_path = filename[len(path):].lstrip(os.sep)
            break

    if resolved_path is None:
        return filename

    parts = resolved_path.split(os.sep)
    # icon-theme/size/category/icon
    if len(parts) != 4:
        return filename

    icon_name = parts[3]

    # strip extension
    return icon_name[:-4]

def get_icon_string(image):
    filename = image.props.file
    if filename is not None:
        return try_icon_name(filename)

    return image.props.icon_name

def strip_extensions(icon):
    if icon.endswith(EXTENSIONS):
        return icon[:-4]
    else:
        return icon

def set_icon_string(image, icon):
    if GLib.path_is_absolute(icon):
        image.props.file = icon
    else:
        image.props.icon_name = strip_extensions(icon)

DESKTOP_GROUP = GLib.KEY_FILE_DESKTOP_GROUP

# XXX - replace with a better UI eventually
class IconPicker(object):
    def __init__(self, dialog, button, image):
        self.dialog = dialog
        self.button = button
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.pick_icon)
        self.image = image

    def pick_icon(self, button):
        chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(title=_("Choose an icon"),
                                        parent=self.dialog,
                                        buttons=(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.REJECT,
                                        Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT))
        response = chooser.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT:
            self.image.props.file = chooser.get_filename()
        chooser.destroy()

class ItemEditor(GObject.GObject):
    ui_file = None

    __gsignals__ = {
        'response': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, (bool,))
    }

    def __init__(self, parent, item_path):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(config.pkgdatadir, self.ui_file))

        self.dialog = self.builder.get_object('editor')
        self.dialog.set_transient_for(parent)
        self.dialog.connect('response', self.on_response)

        self.build_ui()

        self.item_path = item_path
        self.load()
        self.resync_validity()

    def build_ui(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def get_keyfile_edits(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def set_text(self, ctl, name):
        try:
            val = self.keyfile.get_string(DESKTOP_GROUP, name)
        except GLib.GError:
            pass
        else:
            self.builder.get_object(ctl).set_text(val)

    def set_check(self, ctl, name):
        try:
            val = self.keyfile.get_boolean(DESKTOP_GROUP, name)
        except GLib.GError:
            pass
        else:
            self.builder.get_object(ctl).set_active(val)

    def set_icon(self, ctl, name):
        try:
            val = self.keyfile.get_string(DESKTOP_GROUP, name)
        except GLib.GError:
            pass
        else:
            set_icon_string(self.builder.get_object(ctl), val)

    def load(self):
        self.keyfile = GLib.KeyFile()
        try:
            self.keyfile.load_from_file(self.item_path, util.KEY_FILE_FLAGS)
        except GLib.GError:
            pass

    def save(self):
        util.fillKeyFile(self.keyfile, self.get_keyfile_edits())
        contents, length = self.keyfile.to_data()
        with open(self.item_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(contents)

    def run(self):
        self.dialog.present()

    def on_response(self, dialog, response):
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            self.save()
        self.dialog.destroy()
        self.emit('response', response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK)

class LauncherEditor(ItemEditor):
    ui_file = 'launcher-editor.ui'

    def build_ui(self):
        self.icon_picker = IconPicker(self.dialog,
                                      self.builder.get_object('icon-button'),
                                      self.builder.get_object('icon-image'))

        self.builder.get_object('exec-browse').connect('clicked', self.pick_exec)

        self.builder.get_object('name-entry').connect('changed', self.resync_validity)
        self.builder.get_object('exec-entry').connect('changed', self.resync_validity)

    def exec_line_is_valid(self, exec_text):
        try:
            success, parsed = GLib.shell_parse_argv(exec_text)

            # Make sure program (first part of the command) is in the path
            command = parsed[0]
            return (GLib.find_program_in_path(command) is not None)
        except GLib.GError:
            return False

    def resync_validity(self, *args):
        name_text = self.builder.get_object('name-entry').get_text()
        exec_text = self.builder.get_object('exec-entry').get_text()
        valid = (name_text != "" and self.exec_line_is_valid(exec_text))
        self.builder.get_object('ok').set_sensitive(valid)

    def load(self):
        super(LauncherEditor, self).load()
        self.set_text('name-entry', "Name")
        self.set_text('exec-entry', "Exec")
        self.set_text('comment-entry', "Comment")
        self.set_check('terminal-check', "Terminal")
        self.set_icon('icon-image', "Icon")

    def get_keyfile_edits(self):
        return dict(Name=self.builder.get_object('name-entry').get_text(),
                    Exec=self.builder.get_object('exec-entry').get_text(),
                    Comment=self.builder.get_object('comment-entry').get_text(),
                    Terminal=self.builder.get_object('terminal-check').get_active(),
                    Icon=get_icon_string(self.builder.get_object('icon-image')),
                    Type="Application")

    def pick_exec(self, button):
        chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(title=_("Choose a command"),
                                        parent=self.dialog,
                                        buttons=(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.REJECT,
                                        Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT))
        response = chooser.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT:
            self.builder.get_object('exec-entry').set_text(chooser.get_filename())
        chooser.destroy()

class DirectoryEditor(ItemEditor):
    ui_file = 'directory-editor.ui'

    def build_ui(self):
        self.icon_picker = IconPicker(self.dialog,
                                      self.builder.get_object('icon-button'),
                                      self.builder.get_object('icon-image'))

        self.builder.get_object('name-entry').connect('changed', self.resync_validity)

    def resync_validity(self, *args):
        name_text = self.builder.get_object('name-entry').get_text()
        valid = (name_text != "")
        self.builder.get_object('ok').set_sensitive(valid)

    def load(self):
        super(DirectoryEditor, self).load()
        self.set_text('name-entry', "Name")
        self.set_text('comment-entry', "Comment")
        self.set_icon('icon-image', "Icon")

    def get_keyfile_edits(self):
        return dict(Name=self.builder.get_object('name-entry').get_text(),
                    Comment=self.builder.get_object('comment-entry').get_text(),
                    Icon=get_icon_string(self.builder.get_object('icon-image')),
                    Type="Directory")

def test_editor(path):
    if path.endswith('.directory'):
        return DirectoryEditor(path)
    elif path.endswith('.desktop'):
        return LauncherEditor(path)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid filename, %r" % (path,))

def test():
    import sys

    Gtk.Window.set_default_icon_name('alacarte')
    editor = test_editor(sys.argv[1])
    editor.dialog.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
    editor.run()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: +1 but didn't test your solution. please link to the original source revision in the repo for others to conveniently verify. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Gnome 42 Alacarte Error `AttributeError: 'LauncherEditor' object has no attribute 'icon_file'`

This error just indicates that you  need  to  choose an icon file image for the command and it will save Menu Item with no error you do  not need  to change the code to  prior version .